# getInstalledRelatedApps() API not detecting the installed app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, smartbanner

I've been trying to implement the getInstalledRelatedApps API to work into my project in a smartbanner using jquery.smartbanner.js, but the relatedApps const as shown below is returning empty, and the state of the promise is always in "pending".  A screenshot of the promise is attached below:

[image]

```
   (async function () {
        alert("running");
        const relatedApps = await navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps();
        alert(relatedApps);
        console.log(relatedApps);
        relatedApps.forEach((app) => {
            console.log(app.id, app.platform, app.url);
        });
        })();
```

The manifest.json is as:

```
{ 
    "name": "Example", 
    "short_name": "Example", 
    "lang": "en-US", 
    "theme_color": "#192c4f", 
    "background_color": "#192c4f", 
    "display": "standalone", 
    "scope": "/", 
    "start_url": "/", 
    "icons": [
    { 
        "src": "images/36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36",
        "type": "image/png" 
    },
    { 
        "src": "images/48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png" 
    },
    { 
        "src": "images/72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png" 
    },
    { 
        "src": "images/96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png" 
    },
    { 
        "src": "images/144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png" 
    },
    { 
        "src": "images/192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png" 
    }
],
    "splash_pages": null,
    "prefer_related_applications": true,
    "related_applications": [{
            "platform": "play",
            "id": "com.example.android"
           
    }]
}
```

The playstore app ID has been doublechecked from the android app side.
any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you follow all of the steps in: [Check if your Android app is installed](https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/#check-android)

Comment: Yep, all the steps followed, everything's done just as the tutorial suggested.

Comment: Facing the same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Change related application object

1- the platform must be "webapp" in the case of PWA

2- url is the full path to the web app manifest of your PWA

"related_applications": [{
"platform": "webapp",
"url": "https://example.com/manifest.json",
}]